# Put value variable AMPscript in a JS variable

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm getting the `var @CodeP = RequestParameter("j")` from an URL.
I want to put getting value in a Javascript value.

I tried in JS  `var Codep =%%=v(@CodeP)=%%;` and `var Codep = Variable.GetValue("@CodeP");`both don't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't valid AMPScript:

```
var @CodeP = RequestParameter("j")
```

You have to do a `@var` by itself and then do a `@set`.  You can't do them both in the same `@set`.

Once that's resolved, there are examples on this page:

[Using Server-Side JavaScript with AMPscript](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/using_server_side_javascript_with_ampscript/)

It'd be something like this using your variables:

```
%%[

var @CodeP
set @CodeP = RequestParameter("j")

]%%

<script runat="server">

  Platform.Load("Core","1");
  var CodeP = Variable.GetValue("@CodeP");
  Write("<br>CodeP: " + CodeP);

</script>
```